# VB.NET Display data from MySql to Datagrid

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I already read all the questions and answers from previous post 
but not fit with my problem

Problem :
I want to display data from db(mysql) to datagrid
but the problem is `MySqlDataReader` doesnt recognize

```
SelectCommand

Fill 

Update
```

as the member of `MySqlDataReader`

I follow the exact same way of code writing from the tutorial 
Why this problem occur ??

Below I attached my code.
I hope someone could help me.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class AdminAddItem
Dim MysqlConnection As MySqlConnection
Dim FoodCommand As MySqlCommand
Dim DataFoodRead As MySqlDataReader
Dim dbDataSetFood As New DataTable

Private Sub btnLoadFood_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadFood.Click
    'declare new connection
    MysqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

    'prepare connection string
    MysqlConnection.ConnectionString =
        "server = localhost; userid = root; password = 1234 ; database = kedaikopimamba_db"

    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        MysqlConnection.Open()

        Dim query As String
        query = "select * from kedaikopimamba_db.foodtable"

        FoodCommand.Connection = MysqlConnection
        FoodCommand.CommandText = query

       DataFoodRead.SelectCommand = FoodCommand
        DataFoodRead.Fill(dbDataSetFood)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSetFood
        dgDisplayItem.DataSource = bSource
        DataFoodRead.Update(dbDataSetFood)


        MysqlConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConnection.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to add the exact error message into the post so we know what problem we are solving.  You should also add the technology (Winforms, WPF, WebForms etc) - the term `datagrid` makes it ambiguous

Comment: You are using a MySqlDataReader like it was a MySqlDataAdapter. Change the declaration of DataFoodRead to be an MySqlDataAdapter

Comment: ive change MySqlDataReader to MySqlDataAdapter error come out 

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

FoodCommand was Nothing.

Comment: im using vb.net, windows form 
mysql workbench

Answer (score 0):

What part to your code is the error? Please let us know to easily identify the problem.

Comment: this part 

 DataFoodRead.SelectCommand = FoodCommand
        DataFoodRead.Fill(dbDataSetFood)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSetFood
        dgDisplayItem.DataSource = bSource
        DataFoodRead.Update(dbDataSetFood)